# Raising money in a visiting country -- legal or not legal?

Tags: usa, canada, tourist-visas

I know you're not legally able to work for money without some form of Visa issued (other countries -> U.S.A.); but if one were to **raise** money, that's not actually working for it. If I come to the U.S.A. and start a campaign to raise money, would that be illegal? Visas mention working for money for "aliens" or non-citizens -- what about just raising money? That's like asking for money, but not working for it.

I'd imagine you could, in some conditions/situations, make lots of money doing this.

The big question is, is this legal? Since one isn't **working** for the money, it seems it should be so.

Raising money seems to be a gray area because it doesn't really count as "working for money."

I'm thinking like Kickstarter or IndieGoGo, but not necessarily in the digital world. Say, for example, a man/woman stands in a street corner and asks for money for some cause, real or otherwise -- that would be **raising** money, not **working** for it, although the person in question is still **getting** money.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. Raising money for a business venture might be counted as doing business. Raising money for a charity that is paying you to do it might be counted as working. Raising money for terrorism will get you a spell in jail. What are you raising money for and how are you doing it?

Comment: Also B visa (the most common U.S. visa?) allow some form of business. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_United_States#Classes_of_nonimmigrant_visas https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_visa

Comment: No, in the examples I'm implying that one is raising money on their own merit for an undisclosed purpose (could be charity) and nobody needs necessarily be paying them -- that is what makes it appear like a gray area and what I am wondering since it may not be work/business related at all.

Comment: maybe the question should be changed to "does soliciting for money on the streets count as working?" or something along those lines

Comment: In terms of raising money for charity, many countries and localities have laws that impose at least some restrictions on charitable fundraising. You often can't just set yourself up in the middle of the sidewalk and announce that you're raising money for "Charity X" unless that charity is registered, has accredited you as a fundraiser for their organization, has obtained a permit, or otherwise satisfied various legal requirements. You'd need to work with your charity of interest and comply with whatever policies they have for fundraising.

Comment: Whether it's charity or not does make a difference - there are often different laws in effect.

Comment: I'm going to hit this one as too broad. The answer varies between yes, no and you will get arrested depending on the country in question and the more precise details of what you would be doing. Pitching to venture capitalists would probably be fine most places. Shaking a collection tin on a street corner probably not.

Comment: That would be volunteer work, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

'Raising' money is no different than earning money. You are increasing your wealth and the money raised is 'taxable' (even though taxes may be waived for various reasons).

While getting a 'gift' would fall outside earning money, once you posted on a crowd funding website, you leave 'gift' getting behind and enter into the realm of soliciting, hence into the world of doing business.  Even street beggars are liable for their earnings because they are solicting, though most earn less than the minimum requiring a tax report to be filed so authorities ignore them.

Comment: While this is true for the case where the OP is ' raising money' for his own expenses, there are plenty of other kinds of 'raising money' where the answer would be different.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. For example, most countries visitor/business visa/visa waivers alow the negotiating of contracts and deals etc. One could argue that pitching a kickstarter is just such a thing, but with lots of people to be negotiated with.

Comment: @DJClayworth - the OP's question reads like they are raising funds for themselves or their business idea.  Either of those falls into business/working.  Granted other concepts may have different answers but that is not what was asked.

Comment: @CMaster - the OP specifically asks without some form of visa, so again your comment doesn't really apply to the question asked.

Comment: @Tom most countries apply rules to visa-waiver entry as well. I intepreted the op when saying "without some form of visa" as meaning work permits/working visas, rather than just permission to enter in general.

Comment: @CMaster - according the the US info on Business purposes allowed under business entry under the category of seeking investment as reason for travel to the USA it lists only one allowed activity - surveying potential business sites and/or leasing premises.  Nothing about raising capital.